# how to retrieve the current state of the list as a JSON string, and a way to restore state from a JSON string

Tags: javascript

- Create an html page that has a numbered list of items.
- A user must be able to add an item to the list, and remove one or more items from the list.
- There must be a way to retrieve the current state of the list as a JSON string, and a way to restore state from a JSON string.

It should work in IE7-9, Firefox, and WebKit. Do not use any external libraries, with one exception: you can use JSON2 (http://www.json.org/json2.js) to handle JSON parse/stringify. You may not use inline event listeners.

I finished the above two parts and I am stuck on the third part I can show the code 
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _"I can show the code"_ - yes please.

Comment: Also: check out http://jsfiddle.com to place your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I finished the above two parts and I am stuck on the third part

1. If you completed the first requirement then you are aware of the HTML necessary to create a numbered list on an HTML document.
2. If you completed the second requirement then you are aware of the JavaScript necessary to dynamically add and remove HTML list elements from a numbered list.
3. Take what you learned in step one and pare it back to a numbered list `<ol></ol>` with no items `<li></li>` or, preferably, no numbered list at all. Then take what you learned in step two and loop through a data structure (e.g. an array) that you've created to dynamically generate your HTML list. Any action taken to the list needs to first apply to your data structure and your HTML should be a view into the contents of that structure.

Comment: Can you please provide an example for third part as mentioned above by you

Comment: Are you asking about `JSON.parse( )` and `JSON.stringify( )` or are you looking for code that you can copy?

Comment: This is urgent and important for me I would appreciate if you can help me with the code I wrote the code myself but I am stuck on how to not use inline event listeners can you provide the complete code based on the above requirements I will also try to work on the code

Comment: Check out [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). You'll want to start by adding an onload listener to `window`. From that event handler you'll be able to add listeners to other elements.

Comment: I tried but I am not getting it can you please help with the complete code

Comment: Post what you have like you were asked a week ago.

Comment: Hi Alfredo did you see the code I would appreciate if you can help me